# Pycharm 5 remote python interpreter in a Docker container: non-zero exit code

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to launch different containers, among these there is one running my python app (based on a custom image which is in turn based on the official python:3.5.1 container) and others containing databases and volumes. I would like to use the interpreter in the container from Pycharm (since one of the cool features added in version 5 is the remote Docker interpreter).
I tried to add it using "Project interpreter > add > remote > docker" and specifying the following:

> **machine name**: default (is the only machine on the host)
>
> **image name**: the name displayed by running `docker ps` representing the
>   app container (I tried with and without "`:latest`" suffix)
>
> **python interpreter path**: I tried both default "`python`" than
>   specifying full path (the one returned by `which python` in the
>   container)

But once clicked ok, Pycharm is unable to find the interpreter and the only output that it gives is: "**non-zero exit code**"!

I really would like to avoid using SSH... so, is there someone which actually is able to connect to a Docker interpreter and can explain me how and what should I do?

ps: I also tried to play with port 2376 (the one Pycharm uses to connect to the container) but it seems already automatically exposed by docker, since I get an error trying to explicitly expose it (EXPOSE 2376 in Dockerfile + PORTS: - "2376:2376" in docker-compose)

**UPDATE:**

By ignoring the issue and clicking on "ok" I get a more useful message (emphasis is mine):

> failed to run generator3.py for docker://myapp:latest/python, exit
>   code 1, stderr: 
>            -----
>            /**opt/webapp/src should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url** beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
>            -----

this left me speechless... why it should complain about paths in the container? (/opt/webapp/src is where the source code of my app is located in the container... how could I have references to the host project in the container?!) 
Perhaps I misunderstood the remote interpreter feature, and I can't use it as I wish, which in my case is to run tests on the container from the host.
(Instead of connecting to it using `docker exec..`).
So my goal would be to use Pycharm to test/debug the code in the container... is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to create a socket from the machine that is running PyCharm to the container on the Python debug port? "default" may be a name your machine does not understand. Try using the container's IP instead. The IP usually starts with 172.

Can you share the docker command line you are using to create the container? From your ps I suppose you are using -P ? Why not -p 2376:2376 instead?

Comment: "default" (like the virtual machine IP) is automatically discovered by Pycharm and you can't change it! I selected it from a dropdown menu listing all the available docker virtual machines. I'm not using -p from the command line, since I use docker compose and as I wrote by using: PORTS: - "2376:2376" in the docker-compose file I get an error (specify PORTS on the config file is the same as running with the -p flag)